# PostGIS ST_LineInterpolatePoint inconsistent results

Tags: leaflet, postgis-2.0

I have a set of items that are a known length along a LineString, so I'm generating a Point and saving in the database using (all geometries are using 4326):

```
point = ST_LineInterpolatePoint(line.geometry, item.metres / line.length)
```

I'm then using Leaflet to display the same LineString and a plugin to display distance markers every kilometre. This works: the displayed distance markers match the known length of the LineString.

The problem occurs when I plot the calculated Points of the items. The results are inconsistent and the position of the items are incorrect, relative to the distance markers (not by a consistent error margin).

Can anyone think what would cause this?

Comment: Some more information... I've used the same data to display markers for each item using Leaflet's GeometryUtils plugin (`GeometryUtil.interpolateOnLine`) rather than the PostGIS `ST_LineInterpolatePoint` function to calculate the position. The results are spot-on.

So why are the PostGIS calculations so inaccurate and is there anything I can do to correct them?

Comment: You could try add geography column to table and try same call on it to see if you get better results. Geography does all the hard work to find suitable local UTM (probably not perfect)

Answer (score 1):

Working with lat/lon (4326) for linear referencing is generally not a good idea. Lat/lon has no notion of meters or straight lines, it just knows coordinates in degrees on a sphere and might therefore give unexpected output when used for calculating relative distance, especially when drawn on a map with different projection (Leaflet uses mercator).

Therefore: first make sure your data is in the right (local) projection. If you really have data that spans the earth, then be aware that the shortest path between two points is not a straight line.
Also, you might consider using OpenLayers instead of Leaflet since it has nicer support for different projections.